# Pattern for Regex match

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching, preg-match-all

Im trying to come up with the regex match for this string but im losing hair.
This is what i have so far for an example pattern.

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('/\(.*?\)*([^,\s][^\,]*[^.\s])/', 'Alpha Romeo (11:00), Honda (11:00 & 12:00), Toyota (11:00, 12:00 & 8:00)', $result);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Desired Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Alpha Romeo (11:00),
    [1] => Honda (11:00 & 12:00),
    [2] => Toyota (11:00, 12:00 & 8:00)
)
```

Comment: what is the exact pattern for you? Name followed by Time ?

Comment: Something like this? http://www.regex101.com/r/eE8hF6 I don't know what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match_all('/[,\s]+(.*?\))/', 'Alpha Romeo (11:00), Honda (11:00 & 12:00), Toyota (11:00, 12:00 & 8:00)', $result);
```

And here's the [output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/OwmEO2):

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Romeo (11:00) 
    [1] => Honda (11:00 & 12:00) 
    [2] => Toyota (11:00, 12:00 & 8:00)
)
```

**P.S.**: I am outputting the `$result[1]` here.

---

### EDIT

The last one missed on `Alpha` for first match. Here's a better pattern:

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('/,?(.*?\))/', 'Alpha Romeo (11:00), Honda (11:00 & 12:00), Toyota (11:00, 12:00 & 8:00)', $result);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

[Link](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Mhz39m).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str = 'Alpha Romeo (11:00), Honda (11:00 & 12:00), Toyota (11:00, 12:00 & 8:00)';

preg_match_all('#[^,\s]{2}.*?\(.*?\)#', $str, $matches);

echo var_export($matches, TRUE);
```

Outputs:

```
array (
  0 => array (
    0 => 'Alpha Romeo (11:00)',
    1 => 'Honda (11:00 & 12:00)',
    2 => 'Toyota (11:00, 12:00 & 8:00)',
  ),
)
```